# 'Cannot insert duplicate key row in object' exception even within transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unique-index

I have a couple of code snippets that are throwing me the above exception even when I expect it to not throw it.

Snippet 1:

```
;WITH CompanyCTE AS
(  SELECT DISTINCT Company
   FROM @Companies c)
MERGE INTO dbo.Company WITH (UPDLOCK) d
    USING CompanyCTE s ON d.Company=s.CompanyName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(Company, UpdateDate)
    VALUES(s.CompanyName, GETDATE())
;
```

Snippet 2:

```
UPDATE tblSESSION
SET SESSION_TOKEN = @SESSION_TOKEN
WHERE USER_TOKEN = @USER_TOKEN

IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblSESSION(USER_TOKEN, SESSION_TOKEN) 
    SELECT @USER_TOKEN AS USER_TOKEN, @SESSION_TOKEN AS SESSION_TOKEN           
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblSESSION WHERE USER_TOKEN = 
                         @USER_TOKEN)
END
```

I have removed irrelevant code, but:

1. Both these are inside a transaction
2. The sprocs have 'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED' on top.

The error message is something like this:

**Cannot insert duplicate key row in object dbo.Company with unique index 'IX_Company_Name'. The duplicate key value is (XYZ Company).**

I am assuming even if my sproc is called at the same time with the same values, the checks should be able to prevent the duplicate key insertion attempts. I am not able to reproduce it in dev environment, but I am getting the error message in the Production logs.
Any insight on what could be the possible case which the check is not able to handle?

Comment: I wouldn't expect something called `USER_TOKEN` to tak on the value "XYZ Company".  Perhaps you have more than one unique constraint.

Comment: The error message is for the first code snippet. The second error message is exactly the same (with the table and index names changed) and hence I did not include it.

Comment: Locks are released in the `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level when not needed for read consistency. Try adding a HOLDLOCK in addition to UPDLOCK hint or use a SERIALIZE hint or transaction isolation level.

Comment: I see. As for the second code, what is the best way to do an upsert? Would it suffice to add a HOLDLOCK in the inner select statement? Will the HOLDLOCK  then be held till the insert is completed?